# How to set different color for each TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

Hi I am new to IOS development. I am trying to give different hex Color for each tableview cell. The following code which change the contentView color does not help.

```
var cellColors = ["F28044","F0A761","FEC362","F0BB4C","E3CB92","FEA375"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCells
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: cellColors[indexPath.row % cellColors.count])
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain "following code which change the contentView color does not help." how doesn't it help? what is it doing that is wrong? what exactly do you want it to do? need more information here

Answer (score 3):

You can't load a **HEX color** using `UIColor(named:)`, what you need is an extension of `UIColor` that can take a string (the hex) and return the `UIColor`.

Add this to your code base:

```
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hex: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hexColor = String(hex[start...])

            if hexColor.count == 8 {
                let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
let color = UIColor(hex: "#\(arrayItem)")
```

More info [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below method in your UIColor extension as below and initialize your colours with the color codes.

```
extension UIColor {
     public convenience init(_ value: Int) {
         let red = CGFloat(value >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255.0
         let green = CGFloat(value >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255.0
         let blue = CGFloat(value & 0xFF) / 255.0
         self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
     }
}
```

And your that method like this:

```
let color1 = UIColor(0xf123ac)
let color2 = UIColor(0xF5B2C1)
```

**Just make sure to prefix your color code with `0x`**.